# wordpress fetch all top level menu in array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, menu

I want to fetch all top level menu in array that are set in menu section from admin panel in wordpress.

please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your themes function.php:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'top_level_new' => __( 'Mail Navigation', 'twentyten' ),
) );
```

The above code blocks allows you to create a separate level of menu.

Just copy and paste the code to create a separate level  of menu.

Go to the wp-admin panel.

Choose the menu from the menu selector, add the pages to the  menu.

The below is the block of code that allows you to fetch the menus in the front end.

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'top_level_new',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

Comment: But this will show all menu items but i just need only top menu items.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function wp_get_menu_array($current_menu) {

    $array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($current_menu);
    $menu = array();
    foreach ($array_menu as $m1) {
        if (empty($m1->menu_item_parent)) {
            $menu[$m1->ID] = array();
            $menu[$m1->ID]['ID']             =   $m1->ID;
            $menu[$m1->ID]['title']          =   $m1->title;
            $menu[$m1->ID]['url']            =   $m1->url;
            $menu[$m1->ID]['children']       =   array();
            $childMenu = array();
            foreach ($array_menu as $m2) {
                if ($m2->menu_item_parent == $m1->ID) {
                    $childMenu[$m2->ID] = array();
                    $childMenu[$m2->ID]['ID']          =   $m2->ID;
                    $childMenu[$m2->ID]['title']       =   $m2->title;
                    $childMenu[$m2->ID]['url']         =   $m2->url;
                    $childMenu[$m2->ID]['children']       =   array();
                    $grandChildMenu = array();
                    foreach ($array_menu as $m3) {
                        if ($m3->menu_item_parent == $m2->ID) {
                            $grandChildMenu[$m3->ID] = array();
                            $grandChildMenu[$m3->ID]['ID']          =   $m3->ID;
                            $grandChildMenu[$m3->ID]['title']       =   $m3->title;
                            $grandChildMenu[$m3->ID]['url']         =   $m3->url;
                            $childMenu[$m3->menu_item_parent]['children'][$m3->ID] = $grandChildMenu[$m3->ID];
                        }
                    }
                    $menu[$m2->menu_item_parent]['children'][$m2->ID] = $childMenu[$m2->ID];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $menu;
}
?>
```